# I have to get only those lines in a text file that contain the filename of the files in another directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep, ls

I have a text file named "my_text_file.txt". I have another directory named "dir".

Now, "my_text_file.txt" has several lines and there is a file name in every line. I want to get only those lines of "my_text_file.txt" that have a filename that is also present in the directory "dir".

I tried something like

```
ls dir -1 | grep my_text_file.txt
```

but doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ls -1 tmp
abc def
bar
foo

$ cat file
stuff
abc def
bar
nonsense
foo

$ xargs -d'\n' -I {} -n 1 < file ls tmp/{} 2>/dev/null
tmp/abc def
tmp/bar
tmp/foo
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    f="dir/$line"
    [[ -f $f ]] && printf "%s\n" "$f"
done < my_text_file.txt
```

Or using xargs you can do:

```
xargs -0 ls -ld 2>/dev/null < <(awk -v ORS='\0' '{print ".foo/"$0}' my_text_file.txt)
```

Comment: O.O - a bit too much I think?

Comment: Rather than looping possibly large set of all files in directory it is much better to loop through files from text file and avoid the grep.

Comment: Makes sense; assuming the file is smaller than the directory listing.

Comment: Your xargs command will fail for files that contain spaces. You need to make it `xargs -d'\n' ...`. The loop will only find regular files, not directories or device files, if that's not desirable behavior then change `-f` to `-e`.

Comment: Oh I has added xargs just as a supplement but yes you're right, it requires `-d` to work with whitespaces.

Comment: I corrected my `xargs` command. Also I believe `-I` will invoke `ls` as many times as the number of lines in the file which I;ve attempted to avoid in my `xargs` command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `oh` to grep:

```
$ ls
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  files.txt

$ cat files.txt
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
hello.txt

$ for n in *; do grep -oh $n files.txt; done
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

Comment: That will fail for files whose names contain spaces and/or globbing characters and/or regexp metacharacters and/or files whose names partially match other files (1.txt would match 11.txt), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You did not say which shell you are using. If you have `bash` or `zsh`, you can use

```
comm -12 <(ls dir) <(sort my_text_file.txt)
```

Whether this works with other shells too, I don't know.